# html2pdf do close of undefined on printing second time

Tags: nativescript

I'm facing an issue related to PDF conversion. When convert any HTML web view initially it will create a PDF file successfully. But when i press back button and came back to convert page and press convert again it will give unknown error.

the stack trace is given below. Since the web pack kind of building app won't show line number where the error is. I couldn't identify the problem.
The web pack always show error in `vendor.js` whatever the error might be So, please tell me why the error is.

```
 Frame: function:'doClose', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.SuperMarket/files/app/vendor.js', line: 863, column: 22
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/nativescript-html2pdf/html2pdf.js.exports.html2PdfFile', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.SuperMarket/files/app/vendor.js', line: 834, column: 9
System.err:     Frame: function:'webpackHotUpdate../views/htmlView/htmlView-page.js.exports.print', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.SuperMarket/files/app/bundle.97e2cabb5862869d3b07.hot-update.js', line: 53, column: 25
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js.Observable.notify', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.SuperMarket/files/app/vendor.js', line: 8847, column:
23
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js.Observable._emit', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.SuperMarket/files/app/vendor.js', line: 8864, column: 18
System.err:     Frame: function:'ClickListenerImpl.onClick', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.SuperMarket/files/app/vendor.js', line: 18674, column: 23
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1203)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1083)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1070)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1050)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1042)
System.err:     at com.tns.gen.java.lang.Object_vendor_18667_32_ClickListenerImpl.onClick(Object_vendor_18667_32_ClickListenerImpl.java:18)
System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215)
System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5601)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
System.err: Caused by: ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
System.err: Caused by: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
System.err:     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPages.writePageTree(PdfPages.java:112)
System.err:     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1256)
System.err:     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:901)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1203)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1083)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1070)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1050)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1042)
System.err:     at com.tns.gen.java.lang.Object_vendor_18667_32_ClickListenerImpl.onClick(Object_vendor_18667_32_ClickListenerImpl.java:18)
System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215)
System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5601)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

Comment: `java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.` looks like after back button cache/history is cleared and webview is empty

Comment: @Narendra yes I'm using page.navigation context and reading objects in it. i got where i did a mistake. thank you. your comment is the answer for this issue.

Comment: @Narendra but how to retain page.navigation Context object in local. is it good to use appsettings.

Comment: @Narendra how to pass context to intent service 'var intent = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);' as i'm opening pdf file using this and when press back it is giving error on second time conversion. So, i decided to pass context data to intent service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests `java.io.IOException: The document has no pages`. Looks like after back button press, cache/history is cleared and webview is empty.
You can store the context in `appsettings`.